# Get Data in between a text in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Lets say I have a URL link

(example : https://www.example.com/cgi-bin/search.cgi?userSearch=int&userPID=1000&userPreference=price&userZip=01612&userLat=12.3456789&userLong=-98.7654321&userIntSelect=2252533&userUID=0=&userPage=7)

I am looking for a code which searches userLat=12.3456789 userLong=-98.7654321 and display just (12.3456789, -98.7654321) as a result. vba or vba excel will help.

And I am pretty new to vba so please bear with me. Thank you!!

Comment: Does the format of EVERY link of interest follow these rules `userLat=[number]&userLong=[number]&`

Comment: one example is not going to be enough to establish a pattern. Share more example URLs. Enough to establish the pattern. Most formulas here will break if the pattern breaks so it's important to know the rules

Comment: Splitting on "?" and then splitting the second part of the resulting array on "&" gives you an array of elements in the format "ParamName=ParamValue": you can loop over those and find the ones you want.

Answer (score 1):

Assumes your string (*URL in this case*) format **ALWAYS** follows the below rules

- Your Latitude number is between `userLat=` and the first `&` after `userLat=`
- Your Longitude number is between `userLong=` and the first `&` after `userLong=`

---

```
Sub Try()

Dim Lat, Lon, Out As String

Lat = Split(Split(Range("A1"), "userLat=")(1), "&")
Lon = Split(Split(Range("A1"), "userLong=")(1), "&")

Out = "(" & Lat(0) & ", " & Lon(0) & ")"
Debug.Print Out

End Sub
```

---

You can also use this -- same result

```
Lat = Split(Split(Range("A1"), "userLat=")(1), "&")(0)
Lon = Split(Split(Range("A1"), "userLong=")(1), "&")(0)

Out = "(" & Lat & ", " & Lon & ")"
```

---

Dropping the link you provided in cell `A1` yields the below result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply @urdearboy that was quick. I tried this code on a command button in excel also on userform however unable to run the code. I'm doing something wrong as I am a complete noob. **Your Latitude number is between userLat= and the first & after userLat=
Your Longitude number is between userLong= and the first & after userLong=** These conditions are TRUE.

Comment: You prob have a different issue with the form. I’m not great at those so that deserves a separate question. This answered your question as it was presented which had no mention of buttons/user forms

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `FILTERXML` (windows excel 2013+) you can use

```
=MID(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1,"&","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[contains(.,'userLat') or contains(.,'userLong')]"),1+FIND("=",FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1,"&","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[contains(.,'userLat') or contains(.,'userLong')]")),99)
```

To return an array of the two elements.

You can then concatenate them using two INDEX functions to return the first and second element, or, if you have it (Excel 2016+), the `TEXTJOIN` function:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,MID(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1,"&","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[contains(.,'userLat') or contains(.,'userLong')]"),1+FIND("=",FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1,"&","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[contains(.,'userLat') or contains(.,'userLong')]")),99))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly on Excel but I am trying for a vba userform type. Thank you so much. @Ron Rosendeld

Comment: You can use the same approach in VBA. But apparently your question does not outline your real requirements.  I suggest you read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then it would probably be best to ask a new question, and provide sufficient information so that a relevant response might be forthcoming.